# Formatting the output in desired way

Tags: java, format, report, output

the following method produces an output.
The only problem with this code is that after the end of report, it adds two extra lines to the file, while the need is only of one empty line.
i have tried various combinations but uanble to proceed.

Can anybody help here?

```
private static void save_player_info(String[][] data, String player) {
    player=player.toLowerCase();
    try {
        PrintWriter printWriter= new PrintWriter(new File("out4.txt"));
        for(int row=1;row<data.length;row++){
            String playerName=data[row][0].toLowerCase();
            if(playerName.indexOf(player)!=-1){
                String[] fields=data[0];
                String[] values=data[row];
                for (int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
                    printWriter.printf("%21s : %s\n",fields[i],values[i]);
                }

                printWriter.print("\n");

            }
        }

        printWriter.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: then keep only one \n in your printWriter...and outside the for loop

Comment: how is that going to solve the problem. The function checks  for the name of player in array, if name matches it writes the stats of player in output file. The output should be

Comment: \n is used for what?

Comment: (player 1 stats) empty line (player 2 stats) empty line

Comment: to add extra line between two records

Comment: Perhaps the last `values[i]` contains `'\n'` at the end?

Comment: so when you have last record to written then it will add two blank lines since you have one "\n" in you both printWriter statements

Comment: yes. I know the problem. I was asking if there is other way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of unconditionally adding a blank line after the inner `for` loop, you should conditionally add a blank line before the inner `for` loop, if not the first time.

Also, you should use `%n` in `printf` for the newline, and `println()` for the blank line. And you should put the `close()` in a `finally` block, or use try-with-resources. Showing `finally` block solution here for Java version independence.

```
PrintWriter printWriter= new PrintWriter(new File("out4.txt"));
try {
    boolean first = true;
    for(int row=1;row<data.length;row++){
        String playerName=data[row][0].toLowerCase();
        if(playerName.indexOf(player)!=-1){
            String[] fields=data[0];
            String[] values=data[row];
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                printWriter.println();
            for (int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
                printWriter.printf("%21s : %s%n",fields[i],values[i]);
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    printWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Nowadays a better recommendation would be to use a "try with resources" rather than use `finally` for the close.

Comment: @RealSkeptic True, but a lot of people asking questions are still using older versions of Java, so without version information, I didn't want to cover two ways of doing it.

Comment: Since Java 6 has been out-of-support since 2013, I think it's safe to use Java 7 idioms by now.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck here for a long time

Comment: @RealSkeptic You'd think, but I was answering another question yesterday, and did change to use try-with-resource, and it turned out that the guy was still on Java 5. I think the important part is the `close()` should always be in a finally block, whether manually or by using try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap an if statement around the line which prints a newline character to check if `row` is less than `data.length`. Also, you can use `println()` instead of `print("\n")`.

```
for(int row=1;row<data.length;row++){
    ...
    if(row < data.length - 1){
        printWriter.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work correctly if the `if` statement is false for the last row.

Comment: Doesn't the question ask to only print one new line at the end?

Comment: @RealSkeptic So is `row` not incremented in the last iteration?

Comment: I see. I suppose I'll edit the answer just to prevent confusion with future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using new line in

```
printWriter.printf("%21s : %s\n",fields[i],values[i]);
```

So you can skip

```
printWriter.print("\n");
```

Comment: This should be the output
(player 1 stats) empty line (player 2 stats) empty line